# CSS Logical Properties and Box-Shadow

Tags: html, css

Is any way to use CSS Logical properties

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Logical_Properties accordion to the box-shadow?

For example, box-shadow: 10px 0 10px #000; and I want that offset-x will change for RTL version of the block. Is that possible?

Comment: `box-shadow` is not a layout property - it only affects how the element is painted - why do you think `box-shadow` is related to Logical Properties?

Comment: To change style based on RTL/LTR text just use the `:dir()` selector.

Answer (score 1):

> For example, `box-shadow: 10px 0 10px #000;` and I want that `offset-x` will change for RTL version of the block. Is that possible?

Yes - but not using CSS Logical Properties - that's completely irrelevant.

Instead, use the `:dir()` selector:

```
.something {
    box-shadow: 10px 0 10px #000;
}
.something:dir(rtl) {
    box-shadow: -10px 0 10px #000;
}
```

Unfortunately (and surprisingly, to me) as of June 2021, only Firefox supports `:dir()`, but you can hack it with the `[dir]` attribute selector assuming that your `<body>`, `<html>` or some other *ancestor element* has the `dir=""` attribute set - but we can add a new rule to handle that case:

```
.something {
    box-shadow: 10px 0 10px #000;
}
.something:dir(rtl) {
    box-shadow: -10px 0 10px #000;
}
*[dir=rtl] .something {
    box-shadow: -10px 0 10px #000;
}
```

Comment: Yeap I know that I could change via dir but is CSS Logical Properties designed for? It is strange when you use CSS Logical Properties for margins, paddings but for box-shadow you have to use old approach with dir

Comment: No, CSS Logical Properties are essentially aliases for properties that control layout w.r.t. text flow - it is not concerned with CSS properties that aren't affected by text flow -  tat's why `background`, `color`, and others are absent from that MDN page's list.